# NfcAdapter.enableReaderMode() Throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I have the following code in the `onCreate()` method of my main Activity:

```
super.mAdapter.enableReaderMode(this, new NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTagDiscovered(Tag tag) {
        MessageBox.show(Login.this, "onTagDiscovered");
    }
}, NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NO_PLATFORM_SOUNDS, null);
```

but this gives a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. I've verified that nothing is null when I reach this code.

```
07-03 11:40:20.249    2637-2637/com.complync.complyncmobile E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.complync.complyncmobile.Login$3
        at com.complync.complyncmobile.Login.onCreate(Login.java:184)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5015)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4794)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 184 is:

```
super.mAdapter.enableReaderMode(this, new NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback() {
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace to your post, this will allow us to see exactly to which class the error refers to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback` [was added in API Level 19](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback.html) (KitKat).

If this exception is occurring the most likely explanation is that the device or emulator you're testing on has a lower API level. Is that the case?

Comment: You are quite right. My device runs 4.1.2. Thank you!